# Place figure in between end of text and bottom of page

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, includegraphics

I currently have a page where the text finishes a quarter of the way down the page. There is a figure on the same page. The figure can either be placed:

- at the top [t]
- at the end of the text [htbp!] or
- at the bottom of the page [b]

However, I would like to place the figure evenly in the space that's left.
Is there a way for the figure to be placed vertically in the center of the empty space between the end of the text and the bottom of the page?

Thank you!

EDIT

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{bla}
\author{Hello}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done. Some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done. 

\begin{figure}[!b]
\centering
\includegraphics*[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

I would like the figure to be where the red square is (i.e. in between the end of the text and the end of the page)

[image]

Comment: please upload your code -- what you desire can be done using `vfill`

Comment: I've uploaded a code example. There are multiple instances where I would like to apply this placement too so a generic solution would be appreciated! thanks in advance for your time

Comment: You can try to slightly reduce the size of the figure. Sometimes even a small change is enough to fit the float (e.g. `width=0.58\textwidth` or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution, assuming this is the last page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{bla}
\author{Hello}
\date{March 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done. Some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done, some work were done. 

\setlength{\intextsep}{\fill}% added above and below
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics*[width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{}
\label{fig:}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for this suggestion! what happens if it's not the last page?

Comment: You will need to reset \intextsep (also used by wrapfig) afterward, and add a \clearpage.